# How do you iterate through HTML links in table to pull data from tables?

Tags: python, html, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape through the table at https://bgp.he.net/report/world. I would like to go through each of the HTML links going to country pages, then grab the data and then iterate to the next list. I'm using beautiful soup and can already grab the data the I want, but can't quite figure out how to iterate through the column of HTMLs.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json


headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'}

url = "https://bgp.he.net/country/LC"
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

country_ID = (url[-2:])
print("\n")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
#print(soup)
data = []
for row in soup.find_all("tr")[1:]: # start from second row
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    data.append({
        'ASN': cells[0].text,
        'Country': country_ID,
        "Name": cells[1].text,
        "Routes V4": cells[3].text,
        "Routes V6": cells[5].text
    })



i = 0

with open ('table_attempt.txt', 'w') as r:
    for item in data:
        r.write(str(data[i]))
        i += 1
        r.write("\n")


print(data)
```

I would like to be able to gather the data from each country into one written text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only tested this with the first 3 links  (got one error with UnicodeEncodeError but fixed that and commented where that was in the code).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

#First get the list of countries urls

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'}

url = "https://bgp.he.net/report/world"
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', {'id':'table_countries'})
rows = table.find_all('tr')

country_urls = []

# Go through each row and grab the link. If there's no link, continue to next row
for row in rows:
    try:
        link = row.select('a')[0]['href']
        country_urls.append(link)
    except:
        continue


# Now iterate through that list
for link in country_urls:

    url = "https://bgp.he.net" + link
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    country_ID = (url[-2:])
    print("\n")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup)
    data = []
    for row in soup.find_all("tr")[1:]: # start from second row
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        data.append({
            'ASN': cells[0].text,
            'Country': country_ID,
            "Name": cells[1].text,
            "Routes V4": cells[3].text,
            "Routes V6": cells[5].text
        })



    i = 0
    print ('Writing from %s' %(url))

    # I added encoding="utf-8" because of an UnicodeEncodeError:
    with open ('table_attempt.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as r:
        for item in data:
            r.write(str(data[i]))
            i += 1
            r.write("\n")
```

Comment: This almost perfect for what I need. Thank you so much. This however rewrites the file each time. I want to add every table output to one file. I believe If I take data list and write to data in that for loop it might get me closer.

Comment: ah ok. good catch, I  didn't think of that. try changing the mode from write `'w'` to append `'a'`. What I mean is, change `with open ('table_attempt.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as r:` to `with open ('table_attempt.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as r:` reply back if that does the trick

Comment: Definitely worked. Instead of a normal txt, I decided to switch to a JSON dump. You can see my code down below. I added some other output as well that would help the user knows whats actually going on since it too roughly 3 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the main table, and send a request to scrape the "report" listing:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'}
def scrape_report(_id):
  _d = soup(requests.get(f'https://bgp.he.net/country/{_id}', headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
  _headers = [i.text for i in _d.find_all('th')]
  _, *data = [[i.text for i in b.find_all('td')] for b in _d.find_all('tr')]
  return [dict(zip(_headers, i)) for i in data]

d = soup(requests.get('https://bgp.he.net/report/world', headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
_, *_listings = [[re.sub('[\t\n]+', '', i.text) for i in b.find_all('td')] for b in d.find_all('tr')]
final_result = [{**dict(zip(['Name', 'Country', 'ASN'], [a, b, c])), 'data':scrape_report(b)} for a, b, c, *_ in _listings]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json


headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0'}
url = "https://bgp.he.net/report/world"
html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

#sorting through table
table = soup.find('table', {'id':'table_countries'})
rows = table.find_all('tr')

country_urls = []

#Grabbing urls from table
for row in rows:
    try:
        link = row.select('a')[0]['href']
        country_urls.append(link)
    except:
        continue


Total_URLs= len(country_urls)


print(Total_URLs, "counties to pull data from")
print("\n")

#Creating text file
with open('table_attempt.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as r:
    json.dumps([])


#Looping through country url list
    for link in country_urls:

        url = "https://bgp.he.net" + link
        html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

#Taking country identifier from url list
        country_ID = (url[-2:])

        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

        data = []

        i=0
        Total_URLs -= 1

#appending to file
        with open('ASN_Info.txt', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as r:
            for row in soup.find_all("tr")[1:]: # start from second row
                cells = row.find_all('td')
                data.append({
                    'ASN': cells[0].text,
                    'Country': country_ID,
                    "Name": cells[1].text,
                    "Routes V4": cells[3].text,
                    "Routes V6": cells[5].text
                })
                json.dump(data[i], r)
                i += 1
                r.write("\n")

            print('Currently writing from data from %s. %s countries left to pull data from.' %(country_ID, Total_URLs))
```